# XSL conditional sort

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to sort XML elements based on their contents, but the sorting criteria depends on the contents. Here's what I'm starting with:

```
<elements>
    <element createdDate="01/02/2001"/>
    <element createdDate="01/02/2001" modifiedDate="01/03/2001"/>
    <element createdDate="01/02/2001" modifiedDate="01/01/2001"/>
    ...
</elements>
```

(MM/DD/YYYY format)

and my expected output is the elements sorted based on modified date, if it exists, and createdDate, if modified date doesn't exist, so something like this:

```
<elements>
    <element createdDate="01/02/2001" modifiedDate="01/03/2001"/>
    <element createdDate="01/02/2001"/>
    <element createdDate="01/02/2001" modifiedDate="01/01/2001"/>
    ...
</elements>
```

Right now my XSLT looks like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/element">
    <xsl:variable name="date">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@modifiedDate">
                <xsl:value-of select="@modifiedDate"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="@createdDate"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:sort select="$date"/>
    (formatting here)
</xsl:for-each>
```

But the sort isn't recognizing the variable date.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to remove the leading slash `/` from the `<xsl:for-each select="/element">`, because `element` is not the root element.

One solution I came up with is concatenating the dates. This way `@createdDate` moves to the front of the compare string if `@modifiedDate` is not present.

```
<xsl:for-each select="element">
  <xsl:sort select="concat(@modifiedDate, @createdDate)" order="descending" />
  <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1):

In xslt 2 you could write

```
<xsl:for-each select="element">
  <xsl:sort select="(@modifiedDate, @createdDate)[1]" order="descending" />
  <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:for-each>
```

or if you are still using xslt 1 you could use

```
<xsl:for-each select="element">
  <xsl:sort select="@modifiedDate|@createdDate[not(../@modifiedDate)]" order="descending" />
  <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:for-each>
```